# saved excel file size is too large VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Hi I have a macro that will copy a raw file then used **=INDEX()** function for matching file

here's my code

```
ActiveSheet.Range("N:N").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX('" & filename1 & folder & "[" & ffname & "]Accounts'!C11,MATCH(C3,'" & filename1 & folder & "[" & ffname & "]Accounts'!C6,0))"
ActiveSheet.Range("N:N").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("J:J").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("N:N").Select
Selection.Delete
```

well there's nothing wrong with the code but my problem is everytime the program will saved the copied data the file size becomes large. from **16KB** to **2,608KB**

I also tried to add this code where the program will Identify the last used cell of the column for matching

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```

is there a way to fix this on macro??

---

by the way this is not the first I used **=INDEX()** function to match data from another files. the rest was okay but only on this sub Acct the file size got bigger than the original file

Comment: Just for verifications do the followings,, 1. Check the Bytes of Original File 2. Copy & paste the data U r suppose to copy using Macro into New file and get the Byte. 3. Then try the macro and find the difference between both. Another,, may possible your data may have padded with unnecessary white spaces.  Another ,, if possible share the file over the cloud and let us examine the exercise. ☺

Comment: @RajeshS thank you for the info,ur right the file does have a white spaces that's why the file got bigger. so I tried to create a new worksheet inside the active workbook then copy the data then paste it on the new worksheet then deleted the previous/first one. now the file size is smaller than the original file :) thank you so much

Comment: great it means using my suggestion the issue has been solved now,, if yes just confirm through Comments so that I can post it as Answer. ☺

Comment: @RajeshS yes it is :) my problem has been solved thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do the followings will solve your issue:**

1. Check the Bytes (Size) of Original File.
2. Copy & Paste the data you are suppose to copy 
   using Macro into New file and get the Byte 
   (Size).
3. Then try the macro and find the difference 
   between both.
4. Another possibility is, your data may have 
   padded with unnecessary white spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You are entering the formula in the entire N column (1048576 cells if you use Excel 2007 or newer), that's why you get a big file, a lot of useless data is saved.

As an example, modifications to you macro to insert `=""` in the entire column A of a new workbook changes the file size from 9KB to 5579KB.
By unzipping the workbook and looking at the sheet's .xml file you can see that each cell has its value set to `0` :

```
<row r="1" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.2">
    <c r="A1" t="s">
        <v>0</v>
    </c>
</row>
```

To solve this issue you should reduce the number of rows you input the formula in. Using the `LastRow` in your question should work if the data is contiguous (no blank cells).

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```